# What can I do to fix a "unsafe symbol" error in Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I wrote a library that provides Java annotations and Scala code.  I'm consuming in Scala, running in IntelliJ

If I don't use any of my annotations everything works fine.  If I use an annotation in my consuming project I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: error reading Scala signature of co.blocke.blog.PayLoad: unsafe symbol Change (child of package scalajack) in runtime reflection universe
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler.unpickle(UnPickler.scala:51)
...
```

If I run from command line providing my library on the classpath, all is well--no errors.  It only blows up inside IntelliJ.

Figuring this has to do with some kind of version collision, I rebuilt my library forcing JDK 1.8 source/target for the built code in sbt, and repackaged my library:

```
  javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8"),
  scalacOptions ++= Seq("-target:jvm-1.8", "-language:_"),
```

I looked at the built class files with a hex editor and confirmed that it is indeed built for JVM 1.8 (they are).

This did not solve the problem.  I added this to my consuming project to confirm which JVM is running:

```
  println("Scala: " + scala.util.Properties.versionString)
  println("Java : " + System.getProperty("java.version"))
```

This showed Scala 2.12.8 and Java 1.8, which matches what I expect.